# Smartplug socket programming using Mac Address and UDP port

Tags: java, python, macos, sockets, udp

I need to access a smartplug device using socket programming . I have the MAC address and UDP port number of the device . Other information like SSID,password , Apps Id, Dev Id, Cmd ID are also present .

Could you please let me know if this can be achieved using Python or Java API . Is there a way in socket programming to access a device using MAC address and get the information sent from a specific UDP port .

Thanks in advance for your help .

Answer (score 0):

You can access the device via a UDP socket, provided you have the IP address of the device as well as the UDP port number.

Both Java and Python have socket APIs so you can use either one.  Just make sure you follow the network protocol defined by the device to be able to read to / write from the device properly.

Comment: The requirement is to access the device through MAC address only , no IP address is available . We have Python codes using IP address and UDP port number but that is not going to work here . Please let me know if there is anything similar for MAC address .

Comment: If you need to communicate at the Ethernet level, then you need a library that allows you to do so.  And if you're doing that, it's highly unlikely that UDP is in use.  There's a C library call libpcap that does this.  I'm not familiar with any Java or Python equivalents.

Comment: Thanks dbush . Actually I got an android app through which the device was accessible . As per specification , this app is using MAC address. However the code of the same is not available . I am looking for similar solution in Linux platform .